# How do you thank someone?

Tags: support

How do I thank someone for giving the right answer.  I tried to make a comment but I was told I needed a reputation.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to thank someone, upvote their answer.

If you don't have enough reputation to upvote, help someone else with *their* question to earn the reputation, then upvote. By doing so, you will have also provided back to the community by helping someone else. This should be more than enough thanks for anyone participating on this site.

Comment: There's also the anonymous feedback buttons.

Comment: @nhinkle … which the team said they wouldn't look into, as far as I've understood.

Comment: A tip I saw recently was favoriting the question until you have enough rep to vote up (15 rep on SuperUser), then go to your profile and the "favorites" tab. They'll all be there and you can upvote them then.

Answer (score 7):

A simple accepted answer will suffice (Tick green arrow under correct answer).

Comment: From the user's profile, it looks like they haven't asked any questions - they might be asking about how to give a "Thank you" to a question/answer they found useful, but did not originally post . . .

Comment: A valid point. I guess the answer would be you can't until you have sufficient rep.

Answer (score -14):

You could just post it, like you did the question you just asked, in the post you made for the original question.

Comment: We don't want "thank you"s to be posted as an answer horrible advice...